# DatePicker widget brakes bootstrap's css

Tags: php, yii2

Now I am building my first project on Yii2. One page has a datepicker field, it's works ok but that feature is braking up my css styles especially on this page. How can I repair?
It's mine form:

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'first_date')->widget(kartik\date\DatePicker::className(), ['pluginOptions' => ['format' => 'yyyy-mm-dd','todayHighlight' => true,'startDate' => 'today','autoclose' => true];])?>
```

I've tried to add Asset but it isn't help.

```
class DatepickerAsset extends AssetBundle{
public $sourcePath = '@bower/bootstrap-datepicker/dist';
public $js = ['js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js'];
public $css = ['css/bootstrap-datepicker.min.css'];}
```

What is wrong?
May be I have to add some options in config/web.php ? Something like that:`'view' => ['theme' => ['class' =>yii\base\Theme::className(), 'basePath' => ]]`

braked fonts
[image: braked fonts]

good view
[image: good view]

Development console:
[image]

Comment: Get used to it, CSS is broken through its very own nature.

Comment: What does broken CSS mean to you? The only way it can "break" is 1) not loading, 2) inappropriate markup, 3) overridden styling, the cascading part of CSS. Can we get a screenshot?

Comment: can you show what issue are ou facing any link or image of the broken css ?

Comment: @MuhammadOmerAslam yes, sure. I've downloaded it in the Question. May be I was wrong not css at all only fonts.

Comment: @Ravenous I've passed screenshoots. May be I was wrong not css at all only fonts. Because the main grid of bootstrap works

Comment: Probably some DatePicker css is overwriting font style. try to analyze your code with the browser debugger for css.

Comment: Is the site available on the web? Can you provide a link?

Comment: @Sfili_81 I did it. Page has double css connections... img in the question. How could I turn it off?

Comment: @Ravenous no, now it's my personal project. Only at localhost. But I've bundled screenshot with css to question.

Comment: Inspect the title "Fiat Punto" in the browser, go to Computed styles and see where it gets `font-family` from.

Comment: @Ravenous I've found. Th widget is adding new version of bootstrap 4.0 which has different types of fonts..

Answer (score 0):

I've found css file which hides main css and refactor that.